# How can I set ImplementationFlags of MethodBuilder to AggressiveInlining

Tags: c#, clr, cil

What I am trying to do is to set the ImplementationFlags of MethodBuilder to AggressiveInlining. I am building some things at runtime just to avoid virtual method invocations, so any additional performance gain is very welcome.

It is weird but it seems that it is impossible for this particular enumeration of MethodImplAttributes enum.

```
methodBuilder.SetImplementationFlags(methodBuilder.GetMethodImplementationFlags() | MethodImplAttributes.AggressiveInlining);
```

Surprisingly it works for .NoInlinig option

I have checkted the MS code here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/reflection/emit/methodbuilder.cs,e22b85296055bc28,references and I can't see any limitations.

Comment: AggressiveInlining was added in .NET 4.0, sounds like you are targeting an older version.

Comment: And how do you check it does not work? I can add AggressiveInlining for example and it shows in IL.

Comment: @Evk you are right. I was verifying the results with IL DASM, which does not show the "aggressiveinlining" implementation flag. .NET Reflector 8.5 also fails to do that.  Only IL Spy does that, but is some weird way (it displays "flag(0100)" instead of the string).